# Simplify $A'B'C'D' + A'B'CD' + A'BCD' + ABCD' + AB'CD'$

Tags: boolean-algebra

> How do you simply the following equation?
>   $$X = A'B'C'D' + A'B'CD' + A'BCD' + ABCD' + AB'CD'$$

Here is what I did:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
X & = & A'B'C'D'+A'CD'(B'+B) + ACD'(B+B') \\
& =& A'B'C'D'+CD'(A'+A) \\
& = & D'(A'B'C'+C)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Relevant: [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: you have done everything fine,but you could simplify it more,please see my answer  ,you need to know that $c'*c=0$ and $c'+c=1$

Comment: @clueless you need to know that $C + C' Y = C + Y$ for any $Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks great. The one improvement that could be made is that the $C'$ is redundant, owing to an identity:

$$ZY'+Y=Z+Y$$

You can deduce this using the absorbtion law $ZY+Y=Y$, and the complementary law $Y+Y'=1$.

Intuitively, when adding part of $Z$ outside of $C$ to $C$, you may as well add *all* of $Z$ to $C$, because the part already inside $C$ will be abosorbed anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did an edit. Could you please not use $X$ since it might confuse the OP (s/he already has an $X$ in the question).

Comment: @JenniferDylan Oh thanks! Yeah I'll switch that.

Comment: does that means that (A′B′C′+C) = (A'B'+C) because of the absorbtion and complementary law?

Comment: @clueless Taking $Y=C$ and $Z=A'B'$, yes.

Answer (score 1):

we can simplify it  much
$(A'B'C'+C)=(C+C')*(C+A'B')$
we can proof it if we open brackets,we get
$(C+C')*(C+A'B')=C+A'B'C+A'B'C'=C+A'B'C'$

so finally we get   $D'*(C+A'B')=C*D'+A'B'D'$   because $C+C'=1$

Comment: hmm i do not under this c+a′b′c+a′b′c′=c+a′b′c′ can u explain?

Comment: sure  ,first what  does equal to  $c+a'b'c$?take  c out of brackets,you get $c(1+a'b')$ right? but $1+k$ in boolean algebra is equal to $1$ regardles any value of $k$

Comment: oh I see it now that you write it that way thanks alot

Comment: good lucks friend,you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

As all above answer pointed towards Absorption Law which is

```
ZY′+Y=Z+Y
```

So here you can apply this law -

```
 = > D′(A′B′C′+C)
 = > D′(A′B′+C)
 = > D′A′B′+D′C
```

which is your answer

Also you can verify this by K-Map that, this is the simplest form possible of this Boolean expression.

[image]